# Loading an image with external js file

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to load an image using an external js file that contains the following:

```
myimage = new Image(1,1);
myimage.src = 'http://myserver.com/pixel.gif';
```

I see the js file loaded and no error in the console, but also no call to my image pixel. Any idea?

EDIT:
After  the first responses I tried the following and it still doesn't work:

```
var myimage = document.createElement("img");
myimage.src = 'http://myserver.com/pixel.gif';
myimage.height = "1";
myimage.width = "1";
document.body.appendChild(myimage);
```

Comment: Does the browser have it cached? Have you tried appending an random string to the end to break the cache?

Comment: I think you probably need to insert the image into the DOM...

Comment: It's not the cache, I cleared it... I'll add some random string just to be on the safe side

Comment: Yeah appending it to the DOM should trigger the request.

Answer (score 1):

## The image needs to be inserted into the page/DOM.

The image will not be called until it is placed into the page/DOM directly, and therefore *loaded*.

What you *want* will happen with something like: `document.body.appendChild(myimage)`

Comment: Can I do that from my js file? I do not have any access to the loading page. I also don't really want the image to be viewed on the page, so it should be hidden if possible.

Comment: Yes, you can do this from your js file. The best way to hide it would be to create a `<div>` which is hidden with `display: none` in its style/css attributes, then put the `<img>` element inside that `<div>` and then `appendChild(divelement)` into the `<body>` element.

Answer (score -1):

There is an example of how to do this at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp by inserting the image into a canvas.

A small modification which I found makes this work better is putting the drawImage line into an img.onload callback like this:

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
var img=document.getElementById("scream");
img.onload(function() {ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);});
```